# How can I get trainable_variables from model subclassing the tf.keras.Model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to get `trainable_variables` from model which is created by subclassing `tf.keras.Model`, but it return `[]`.I know it works when using `tf.keras.Sequential`.

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
        self.des = tf.constant([[1.,2.]])

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        # y = self.des
        return self.dense2(x)

model = MyModel()
print(model.trainable_variables)  #=>[]
```

I tried feedding some values to the model but it still returns `[]`.

Comment: You have to build the model first, which can be done by calling model(inputs), where inputs is your input data and model is MyModel()

Comment: @name.disp I tried but it still returns `[]`.

Comment: that's quite strange. copy-pasting your code and adding `inputs = np.ones((10, 5))` `outs = model(inputs)` `print(model.trainable_variables)` correctly prints the weights and biases as expected. Can you try creating a new conda env with a fresh tf installation and try again?

Comment: After reinstalling tensorflow... It did work as name.disp suggested.